# Nginx - homepage redirects to /index

Tags: nginx

I am trying to configure nginx to serve pure static html pages. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

The issue is as follows: 
When trying to enter my website by url: http://www.mywebsite.com/ it changes URL automatically to http://www.mywebsite.com/index .

When using http://www.mywebsite.com/index.html it also changes URL to http://www.mywebsite.com/index - but I assume it's because of the rewrite rule which removes the .html extension from uri.

I would like to remove the silly "/index" ending when using both "/" and "index.html". I have found a solution, but not sure though if it's a "proper" one:

```
# If URI equals '/' then find index.html static page
location = / {
        try_files /index.html $uri =404;
}

# After rewrite homepage URI equals '/index', it rewrites it to '/'
location = /index {
        rewrite /index / permanent;
}
```

I have attempted to configure it by using simple try_files without any rewrites, returns etc. But still it always changed URI to "/index" no matter what, for the homepage.

My configs:

sites-available/mywebsite.com content

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name _;

        # remove the .html extension from request URI
        rewrite ^(/.*)\.html(\?.*)?$ $1$2 permanent;

        root /var/www/mywebsite.com;
        index index.html;

        # redirect rules for homepage '/', removes 'index' from URI
        include /etc/nginx/sites-available/conf/redirects-homepage-template.conf;

        # rule for any URI content. Searches for static file with .html extension or exact URI content file name. If not found, returns 404.
        location / {
                try_files $uri.html $uri =404;
        }
}
```

redirects-homepage-template.conf content

```
# Rules for handling homepage redirects

# If URI equals '/' then find index.html static page
location = / {
        try_files /index.html $uri =404;
}

# After rewrite homepage URI equals '/index', it rewrites it to '/'
location = /index {
        rewrite /index / permanent;
}
```

The website is meant to serve only static content and it's suppose to work as fast as possible. I wonder about the consequences of my solution and if there's any better way of removing the silly "/index" from homepage.

Haven't configured domain yet, using bare ip address for testing purpose.

Comment: Do you clear the browser's cache before testing?

Comment: @RicharSmith yes, I did, even did the classic turn off and on the browser and clear all history, cookies etc.